# pdf.js - page fadein/fadeout effect in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fadein

I'm using pdf.js to display some PDFs.
All works fine, but now i'm trying to add some improvement like effects when i click on prev/next buttons.

I'd like to have a fadein/fade/out transition between the pages but I can't figure out how can I do that.
I'm super new to JS, so i need help.

The pdf renders into `the-canvas` div

Here's my code:

```js
function queueRenderPage(num) {
  if (pageRendering) {
    pageNumPending = num;
  } else {
    renderPage(num);
  }
}



/**
 * Displays previous page.
 */
function onPrevPage() {
  if (pageNum <= 1) {
    return;
  }
  pageNum--;
  queueRenderPage(pageNum);
}
document.getElementById('prev').addEventListener('click', onPrevPage);

/**
 * Displays next page.
 */
function onNextPage() {
  if (pageNum >= pdfDoc.numPages) {
    return;
  }
  pageNum++;
  queueRenderPage(pageNum);
}

document.getElementById('next').addEventListener('click', onNextPage);
```

```html
<script src="//mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.js"></script>

<canvas id="the-canvas"></canvas>

<div id="prev" class="prev-next">&lt;</div>
<div id="next" class="prev-next">&gt;</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved on my own. I don't think it's the nices solution, but still...

```
$('#next').click(function(){
  $("#the-canvas").fadeOut(0);
  $("#the-canvas").fadeIn(500);

  onNextPage();
})
```

Then do the same thing with `id="prev"`.